# Calling the finish() method of an Activity from a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, methods, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have 2 Activities (Activity1, Activity2) and a BroadcastReceiver class

Assume that we are now on Activity2, where I set up an AlarmManager to run at a specific time.

Is there a way to call the finish() method of Activity2 within the onReceive() of the BroadcastReceiver?

My goal is to return to Activity1 from Activity2 without starting a new Intent in onRecieve().

Note: The BroadcastReceiver class is not registered within the Activity of Activity2. It is registered in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can call finish() on the onReceive method. Do remember to unregister your listener on the OnDestroy. If Activity1 has already been initialized Android will activate Activity1. I am assuming you are opening the activities in a sequence.

Comment: This works when the BroadcastReceiver is registered within an Activity. However, my BroadcastReceiver is setup where the class is separate from the Activity and the AndroidManifest.xml handles the registration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Activity2class.finish();